# How can I send a REST XML POST request via curl?

Tags: http, rest, curl, jaxb, http-post

Basically, I have a project set up in Restlet which uses JAXRS for mapping resources to paths and uses JAXB for serializing and deserializing XML to/from Java types. I'm currently trying to send a POST request in order to test whether it works, and I'm running into a bit of trouble. Here's my resource:

```
@Path("stream")
public class StreamResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes("text/xml")
    @Produces("text/xml")
    public Stream save(Stream value) {
        logger.debug("saving new stream...");
        return (Stream)this.streamPersistence.save(value);
    }
}
```

Here's my `Stream` class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="stream")
@XmlType(propOrder={"id", "streamName", "title", "description", fileSystemPath"})
public class Stream {

    private Long id;

    private String streamName;

    private String fileSystemPath;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    // getters/setters omitted for brevity
}
```

And here's how I'm invoking `curl`:

```
curl -X POST -d '<stream><streamName>helloWorld.flv</streamName><title>Amazing Stuff, Dude!</title><description>This stream is awesome-cool.</description><fileSystemPath>/home/rfkrocktk/Desktop/helloWorld.flv</fileSystemPath></stream>' --header 'Content-Type:"text/xml"' http://localhost:8888/stream
```

Here's the error I'm getting from `curl`:

```
The given resource variant is not supported.
```

...and here's the error in Restlet:

```
15:02:25.809 [Restlet-961410881] WARN  org.restlet.Component.Server - Error while parsing entity headers java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal token: "text
    at org.restlet.data.MediaType.normalizeToken(MediaType.java:647)
    at org.restlet.data.MediaType.normalizeType(MediaType.java:686)
    at org.restlet.data.MediaType.<init>(MediaType.java:795)
    at org.restlet.data.MediaType.<init>(MediaType.java:767)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.header.ContentTypeReader.createContentType(ContentTypeReader.java:84)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.header.ContentTypeReader.readValue(ContentTypeReader.java:112)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.header.ContentType.<init>(ContentType.java:99)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.header.HeaderUtils.extractEntityHeaders(HeaderUtils.java:664)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.createInboundEntity(Connection.java:313)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.ServerConnection.createRequest(ServerConnection.java:136)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.ServerConnection.readMessage(ServerConnection.java:229)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.readMessages(Connection.java:673)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Controller$2.run(Controller.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

What am I doing wrong here? This seems pretty straightforward, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `text/xml`.

In other words you want

```
curl -X POST -d '<stream><streamName>helloWorld.flv</streamName><title>Amazing Stuff, Dude!</title><description>This stream is awesome-cool.</description><fileSystemPath>/home/rfkrocktk/Desktop/helloWorld.flv</fileSystemPath></stream>' --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' http://localhost:8888/stream
```

Answer (score 0):

curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X POST --data-binary "@token.xml" URL